# Ionic Native Android permissions vs diagnostic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

While working on Ionic(Android), i came across issues with android permissions

I found two different plugins :

[Diagnostic Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/)

and

[Android Permissions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/)

want to know what is the difference between the two, and which plugin to use in an Ionic 3 app.

Also, My platform target is not just android , i want it for bot android and ios.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution?